# Irreducible subspaces in the space of functions on Grassmannian acted by $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\Gr{Gr}$Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field with $q$ elements. Let $\Gr_{i,n}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ denote the Grassmannian of linear $i$-dimensional subspaces in $\mathbb{F}_q^n$.

The group $\GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ acts on the space of complex valued functions on $\Gr_{i,n}(\mathbb{F}_q)$. By Proposition 5.1 in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.08675) paper it is multiplicity free and has the length $1+\min\{i,n-i\}$.

**Is there an explicit description of irreducible subspaces?** The simplest unknown to me case is $n=4,i=2$.

Comment: So this is a parabolic induction of the trivial representation from a maximal parabolic.

Comment: @KentaSuzuki: Correct. Does it imply something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $j\leq i$, functions on $\operatorname{Gr}_{j,n}(\mathbb F_q)$ map to functions on $\operatorname{Gr}_{i,n}(\mathbb F_q)$ by sending the delta function on a $j$-dimensional subspace to the characteristic function of the set of $i$-dimensional subspaces containing that $j$-dimensional subspace.

I believe one knows this map is injective if $j \leq i \leq \frac{n}{2}$.

This gives a filtration of the space of functions on $\operatorname{Gr}_{i,n}(\mathbb F_q)$ (for $i \leq n/2$, but symmetry handles the opposite case) by the images of these maps. The filtration gives a decomposition, where the $j$th summand of the decomposition is the intersection of the image of the map from functions on $\operatorname{Gr}_{j,n}(\mathbb F_q)$ with the perpendicular of the image of the map from functions on $\operatorname{Gr}_{j-1,n}(\mathbb F_q)$.

The numbers of summands in this decomposition is $1+i$ and each is nontrivial for dimension reasons so these summands must be the irreducible components.